# Extract exact value from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get a XML value from some XML, here is my XML

```xml
<SearchResult>
  <Entity id="192418" defaultrole="TEMP_JOB_R">
    <Property name="JOB_GEN">
      <Attribute name="REFERENCE">192418</Attribute> 
    </Property>
  </Entity>
</SearchResult>
```

I have tried this

```c#
var reference = (
  from el in result.XPathSelectElements("Entity")
  select el.Attributes("REFERENCE").Select(x => x.Value).SafeParse<long>().FirstOrDefault()
);
```

However reference is always equal to 0
How can I select the reference attribute and pull back just its value?

Comment: There is not `REFERENCE` attribute. There is a `Attribute` element, with a attribute called `name` and the value `REFERENCE. What you are looking for simply doesn't exist in your XML.

Comment: I want to get the value "192418"

Comment: You want XPath along the lines of: `SearchResult/Entity/Property/Attribute[@name='Reference']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in a solution using XPath expression, the following XPath will select `<Attribute>` elements having `name` attribute equals `REFERENCE` :

```
var reference = (from el in result.XPathSelectElements("//Entity/Property/Attribute[@name='REFERENCE']")
                 select (long)el
                 );
```

Or if you expect only single result :

```
var reference = (long)result.XPathSelectElement("//Entity/Property/Attribute[@name='REFERENCE']");
```

Side note: You can just [cast `XElement` to `long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354405%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as demonstrated above.